# Align without using float

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to make my website responsive but I'm having a bit of trouble. When the screen sizes down the navigation links move underneath the logo. Because I used  `float:right` I had to put the navigation links in reverse order. I also want the logo to scale with the navigation but I haven't figured that out yet either using the `wrappers`.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9YsK/

Comment: Um, use float:left instead?

Comment: You need to use CSS Media Queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:inline` it is actuallythe preferred method of aligning menu items

See the [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/y9YsK/3/) adjustments

p.s. My corrections did not allow for responsiveness. If you need the menu to remain horizontal when sizing the window down, you must use @media queries and a responsive framework to do get that effect. Not to mention a hamburger menu for when the size has been reduced to less that 480px. Other than that. It works great

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate all the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Float can be a pain... Try changing the display:

```
.wrapper
{
  display:inline-block
}
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

As said previously, you must use media queries for this. You're website is currently more flexible than responsive.

By the way, you don't have to float the links in reverse order. You can either use display:inline or set the li elements to `float:left` and then set the ul element to `float:right`. That makes your markup a little bit cleaner.

Mozilla has a pretty good guide on using media queries that you can check out if you like. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries